# What's the meaning of: Ça me changeait beaucoup de ma maison...?

Tags: sens

> *L'appartement se trouvait au neuvième étage d'une immense tour en plein centre-ville. **Ça me changeait beaucoup de ma maison tranquille à la campagne en France!***

I know the last sentence have to mean something around: it was very different from my... France.

But the literal translation doesn't match this at all: That changed me a lot from my..France.

I tried to check [the various meanings](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/changer) of 'changer' but I couldn't find something that fits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Ça me change de* sth is close to "it is a change for me from sth" so here the meaning is :

> It was a big change for me from my peaceful/tranquil house in the countryside in France! (Thanks to @Caltor)

Comment: The meaning is obviously spot on, but to mirror the original text, I think a more literal translation of the second sentence would be "It was a big change for me from my peaceful/tranquil house in the countryside in France!"